# Footer disappears at a certain content length

Tags: html, css, drupal

So, i was very excited this morning when I found i could edit the html of my Drupal content page. However, upon testing the code and adding a second article, a scroll bar appeared but my footer disappeared. If you look on this site:
 [tobynews.com/postit/node/](http://www.tobynews.com/postit/node/)

at the source code (towards the bottom) you'll find the footer, but when you look at the page there is no footer. I've tried removing body padding, adjusting height, etc. but nothing really seems to work. It also seems to happen on another page of mine. I'm wondering if maybe there is just a certain height that it must stay in. I have little experience with footers so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `#footer` from `position: fixed` to `position: relative`.